# How to get randon name in python

Tags: python

I'm using a site that creates python forms to send an excel file to register products on a site. In another question, someone helped me to name the file with random numbers - because as there will be multiple users uploading the files, saving them with the same name would overwrite them.
My question is: I created a function that saves the file after the user sends the file through the input:

And, as I need to make multiple requests to register this product, I need to reload this same excel file every time a new request starts. The reason is that to register this product, I need the Id of the requests to proceed with the registration.
That way, I open the file with load_workbook() and ask to save the Id in a column inside the excel file that I determine in the code, and then save. And I do this 3 more times.
Is there a way to get the name of the file that was generated in the save_file function so that you can access it every time a request starts?

Here's my code:

```
sendFile = False
def save_file(excelFile, path):  
  open(path, 'wb').write(excelFile.content)
while sendFile == False:  
  fileR = read_file("Excel file", button_text="Send")
  if "xlsx" in fileR.url:
    sendFile = True,
  else:
    display("Please, send an Excel File .xlsx", button_text="Back")
save_file(fileR, f'/app/workspace/Sheet{random.randint(1,99999)}.xlsx')
```

This is the way I access the file after saving it in the save_file function

```
df = pd.read_excel(f'/app/workspace/{save_file}')
```

after looping through excel columns through .loc, i open excel like this:

```
create_product = load_workbook(f'/app/workspace/{save_file}')
```

And then, save the product.

The fileR, display, button are all features of this form

Comment: Of course you can.  You just need to save the generated name in a string variable, and pass the string variable to `save_file`.  How will you associate the name with a user?

Comment: @TimRoberts but how can i get the generated name?

Comment: `name = f'/app/workspace/Sheet{random.randint(1,99999)}.xlsx')` and then `save_file(fileR, name)`, and now you have the name in `name`.

Comment: Maybe you could use `datetime` to name the file by second (or millisecond) with `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S` eg `20220707113044`

Comment: @TimRoberts thank you! but when I try to access with pd.read_file, it gives this error:
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/workspace//app/workspace/Planilha70632.xlsx'

Answer (score 0):

Save the random int in a variable before using it and you can use it wherever you want

```py
rand = random.randint(1,99999)
save_file(fileR, f'/app/workspace/Sheet{rand}.xlsx')
```

you can then pass it into your `pd.read_excel()` like this

```py
df = pd.read_excel(f'/app/workspace/Sheet{rand}.xlsx')
```

if you need to get the filename from the path for some reason you can use a [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095710/extract-filename-using-regex).

Comment: Thank you so much! Your help and TimRoberts were incredible! Both ways worked